# How can I use dynamic key for struct in Go lang?

Tags: go

I have this struct for get data from Json string.

```
    type msg struct {
         Msg1 string   `json:"msg1"`
         Msg2 string  `json:"msg2"`
         Msg3 string `json:"msg3"`
    }
```

And I need to use this struct like below.

```
num := // some random number under 3
data := msg.Msg + num  // as msg.Msg1, msg.Msg2...
```

How can I do this in Go lang?
I searched a lot but couldn't find any good solutions.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number or how to convert a string to a number?

Comment: You can only do that by using reflection. See [`FieldByName`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.17.8#Value.FieldByName)

Comment: Go is a statically typed langauge, types must be known at compile time. If `msg.Msg + num` would be valid, its type would be unknown (different fields could have different types). What you want is only possible with reflection as @mkopriva suggested.

Comment: Generally if you need such construct, use a map where the field name can be the map key. And if you only need to differentiate by a number, then use a slice which you can index.

Comment: You need a slice or an array. `type msg string[3]` for example, using an array. Then you can index it with `num`

Comment: Are you looking for a [map](https://gobyexample.com/maps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Show You How To Using Json And Map ,May be helpful

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)
type sample struct{
    Member1 string `json:"TheMember1"`
}


func main() {
    map_contains := make(map[string]string)
    //Part 1 Direct Add to Map
    map_contains["w"]="mmmmm"
    fmt.Println(map_contains)
    fmt.Println(map_contains["w"])
    
    //Part 2 JsonString to Map
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"a":"123"}`),&map_contains)
    fmt.Println(map_contains)
    fmt.Println(map_contains["a"])

    //Part 3 Struct To JsonString To Map
    s1:=sample{
        Member1:"June",
    }
    s1json,err:=json.Marshal(s1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(s1json))
    json.Unmarshal(s1json,&map_contains)
    fmt.Println(map_contains)
    fmt.Println(map_contains["TheMember1"])
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I know this... I just wanted to know that I can approach the map or struct data using key with variable like `data["Msg"+1]`

Comment: import  "strconv"  data["Msg"+strconv.Itoa(1)]

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use dynamic key for struct in Go lang?

You simply cannot. This is not doable in Go.

(Use a map if you need this.)

Comment: Sorry, but then how can I get the value with variable in map key like this? `data["Msg"+1]`